# ios development - understanding xcode console output

Tags: ios, console

When i log a dictionary for example i get a output like this:

```
2013-04-18 16:24:45.905 pathFinderTest[9650:c07] -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9271ee0
2013-04-18 16:24:45.912 pathFinderTest[9650:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9271ee0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d1c4bd 0x1c80bbc 0x1c8094e 0x1c07c36 0x1c5113c 0x1cb64b6 0xb3c60a 0xb3c57c 0x2af7 0x28f8 0xf41c7 0xf4232 0x433d5 0x4376f 0x43905 0x4c917 0x25a5 0x10157 0x10747 0x1194b 0x22cb5 0x23beb 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1117a 0x12ffc 0x22dd 0x2205)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Now i know where the error was and in what file. But what if i didn't?
I'm used to java where it points to the correct file and the corresponding line number. Not that that is always the line where the problem is but often it is a good direction.

Comment: You have a `NSDictionary` instance that you are treating as it was `NSString`. For further advice look at @rmaddy's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the app using the debugger, when you encounter an exception, the Xcode debugger will show a stack trace. This will point you at the exact file and line in your app that caused the problem.

If this isn't happening then do the following in Xcode:

- View the breakpoints pane on the left side of Xcode
- Tap the + button in the bottom left corner and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint"
- A new breakpoint appears along with a dialog. Accept the defaults and click on Done
- Right-click on the exception and select "Move Breakpoint to" and choose "User"

Now debug your app and cause an exception. You should now get a useful stack trace in the debugger whenever you encounter an exception.